# Can I use an Xbox One giftcard to buy a 360 game for my Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, backwards-compatibility

I want to buy Fallout 3 for my Xbox One using a 15 dollar giftcard I recently received. I have already put the money in my account and I was wondering if I could use it to buy the game, as it is a 360 game, but is compatible with the One. Thanks!

Comment: Xbox One is not backwards compatible. Fallout 3 cannot run on it.

Comment: Note how this doesn't include the Xbox One platform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallout_3

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2, xbox one features an xbox emulator, and fallout 3 is a supported title. They even package the Xbox one version of Fallout 4 with an Xbox 360 code for Fallout 3.

Comment: @Timelord64 Ah, I see. Good on Microsoft, then.

Answer (score 2):

**Most certainly**.

Prepaid cards for Microsoft funds transfer into your accounts funds, which are usable across all store platforms.

You should be able to use the funds from your Xbox 360, Xbox One, or any platform (computer, tablet or phone) running Windows 8 or 10, provided you are accessing the store from the same Microsoft account.

Comment: I tried to install a game on the xbox store on my laptop but it says "You have no valid payment options on file." Any way to fix this?